# How to correctly enable Type checking in VSCode for LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, js

I wonder how to sucessfully configure type checking in VSCode for LWC.
VSCode has JS/TS compiler that support type checking when we set *jsconfig.json* with `compilerOptions` like below:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "checkJs": true
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "c/sharedCode": [
            "sharedCode/sharedCode.js"
        ]
    } // Do I need to provide paths for all my components explicitly?
}
```

with VSCode *settings.json* `"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,`. Funcionality of type checking gets correct types from JSDoc comments placed in code.

Type checking works as expected but imports ends with some problems:

In Jest Tests:

```js
import { createElement } from "lwc";
```

`Module '"lwc"' has no exported member 'createElement'.ts(2305)`

Is it connected with [this](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/pull/2010)?

When compiler path is not set:

```js
import SharedCode from "c/sharedCode";
```

`Cannot find module 'c/sharedCode'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? ts(2792)`